# Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating application in react using router below is my code

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

app.jsx

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./Pages/Home"

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

home.jsx

```
import Header from "../Components/Header/Header";

function Home() {
  return <><Header /></>
}

export default Home;
```

dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^18.2.64",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.21",
  "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
  "eslint": "^8.57.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
  "vite": "^5.1.6"
}
```

And I am getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined at new Router

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The error you see is caused by importing and using the low-level `Router` component which has a couple required props.

See [Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router):

```js
declare function Router(
  props: RouterProps
): React.ReactElement | null;

interface RouterProps {
  basename?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  location: Partial<Location> | string; // <-- required!
  navigationType?: NavigationType;
  navigator: Navigator;                 // <-- required!
  static?: boolean;
}
```

It's the missing `location` prop that has the `pathname` property that the router needs.

You can see in [source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/9e7486b89e712b765d947297f228650cdc0c488e/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L448) where the low-level `Router` attempts to destructure from the undefined `location` prop.

```js
export function Router({
  basename: basenameProp = "/",
  children = null,
  location: locationProp, // <-- no default/fallback value
  navigationType = NavigationType.Pop,
  navigator,
  static: staticProp = false,
  future,
}: RouterProps): React.ReactElement | null {
  .....

  if (typeof locationProp === "string") {
    locationProp = parsePath(locationProp);
  }

  let {
    pathname = "/", // <-- attempted destructure from undefined!
    search = "",
    hash = "",
    state = null,
    key = "default",
  } = locationProp;

  ....
}
```

You are also missing other key parts of the React-Router v6 API in the other components, i.e. all `Route` components need to be rendered into a `Routes` component which holds the path matching logic, and the `Route` component API changed significantly as well.

## Solution

You'll pretty much never need to use the low-level `Router` component. You should instead use one of the high-level routers, e.g. `BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, `MemoryRouter`, etc, which all implement and incapsulate the base required props of the `Router` component.

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Update the rendering of routes in your `App` component to wrap all `Route` components in a `Routes` so they can be matched, and update your `Route` components to use the correct `element` prop to render the routed content. The `element` prop expects a `React.ReactNode`, or more colloquially known as JSX.

app.jsx

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./Pages/Home"

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      ... other routes ...
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For more complete details see:

- [Migrating from v5 guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5)
- [Main Concepts](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts)
- [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)
- [Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes)
- [Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route)

Answer (score 0):

Each `<Route>` should be a direct child of `<Routes>`.

---

Change your main to:

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <App/>
      </BrowserRouter>>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

And then defined all your `<Routes>` and `<Route>` in `App`:

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Routes>
         <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
      </Routes>
  )
}
```

---

For more examples, take a look at the [official examples](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/basic) provided by React Router.

Answer (score 0):

React router dom the API recieved some changes
You need to change router in your main to browser router:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App/>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

than in your app.jsx you also need to change **component** prop to **element** and pass JSX directly

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This should fix the **Uncaught TypeError**